# XCTest - How do you create multiple Key Modifier Flags using Command and Shift?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, ios-ui-automation

There are not too many posts related to using the XCUIElement.KeyModifierFlags.

I'm currently using XCode 8.3 and specifically interested in using the following Modifier Flags in conjunction with selecting keyboard characters.

```
static var command: XCUIElement.KeyModifierFlags

static var shift: XCUIElement.KeyModifierFlags
```

Can someone provide an example of how to use multiple flags with either `typeKey(_:modifierFlags:)` or `perform(withKeyModifiers:block:)` to perform a key combination such as command + shift + h?

Comment: The question is tagged with iOS but I think this API is only available for macOS.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do `cmd`+`shift`+`h` using the `typeKey` method

```
textfield.typeKey("h", modifierFlags: [.command, .shift])
```

Comment: Thanks.. but it doesn't look like that is available until Xcode 9.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500604-typekey it is available on Xcode 7.2